# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de fondo de una celda comparándolo con la fecha actual?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una página con PHP y la base de datos MySQL y hay una cosa que no soy capaz de hacer: Una de las columnas es la fecha tope para realizar un trabajo y quiero que, cuando falten 10 días para esa fecha, el color de fondo de la celda cambie de color y lo mismo para cuando la fecha se haya superado.

Ya tengo una cosa similar para otra celda que lo que hace es cambiar el fondo comparándolo con un texto. Lo estoy haciendo con un `switch` y me imagino que con este comando se puede hacer, pero no sé cómo comparar con la fecha actual.

Os lo adjunto todo a ver si me podéis solucionar algo.

Ésta es la consulta a la base de datos:

```
   <?php
    require_once 'connection_simple.php';
    $result;

    $conn = dbConnect();
    // Create the query
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM preventivos WHERE ID_GRUPO_ASIGN="pendiente"  ORDER BY id asc';
    // Create the query and asign the result to a variable call $result
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    // Extract the values from $result
    $rows = $result->fetchAll();
    // Since the values are an associative array we use foreach to extract the values from $rows
 ?>
```

Y como imprimo las celdas:

Todas van impresas con este formato:

```
<td><?php echo $row['NOM_GRUPO']; ?></td>
```

Y la que quiero cambiar el color de fondo sería ésta con el `switch`, habría que modificar los `case` con lo que corresponda, yo ahora simplemente he puesto "<10" y "> actual" (a modo de ejemplo):

```
<?php switch ($row['FEC_EJECUCION']){
    case 'Avila':
        echo "<td bgcolor='#58fa82'>$row[FEC_EJECUCION]</td>";
        break;

    case 'Pendiente llevar':
        echo "<td bgcolor='#f78181'>$row[FEC_EJECUCION]</td>";
        break;
        default:
        echo "<td>$row[FEC_EJECUCION]</td>";
        break;
        }
?>
```

Desde aquí

```
<?php

$date = strtotime($row[FEC_EJECUCION]);

$diff = date_diff(date(), $date);

$mayor = 0; //por defecto, falso

echo '<h1>'.$diff->d.'</h1>'; 
//ESTO DEBERÍA DIBUJAR UN H1 con la diferencia de fechas en días

if(($diff->d)>=10) //tomo la cantidad de días y si es mayor o igual a 10, entra
{
   $mayor = 1; //Verdadero
}
switch ($mayor){
    case 1: //si es mayor a 10
        echo "<td bgcolor='#58fa82'>$row[FEC_EJECUCION]</td>";
        break;

    case 0: //si no es mayor
        echo "<td bgcolor='#f78181'>$row[FEC_EJECUCION]</td>";
        break;
        default:
        echo "<td>$row[FEC_EJECUCION]</td>";
        break;
        }
?>
```

Comment: el codigo no soy capaz de que salga todo junto, espero que se entienda

Answer (score 1):

Convierte tu valor a timestamp y compara con el timestamp de la fecha actual, obtenida con date().

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row[FEC_EJECUCION]);
```

Ejemplo:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row[FEC_EJECUCION]);
$timestamp_comparar = strtotime($mdate_referencia);
$bg_color ="#FFF";
if ($timestamp<$timestamp_comparar) {$bg_colo="#000";}
<td style="background='".$bg_color."'">My valor</td>
```

Comment: me podrias indicar en que parte del codigo iria lo que me comentas, entiendo lo que me comentas pero soy bastante nuevo como para implantarlo je je

Comment: Paco no sé en que formato tienes FEC_EJECUCION, pero imagino que es un date de mysql tipo "2017-05-22", para comparar con la fecha de hoy o la que quieras usar debes convertirlas a medidas de tiempo comparbles y eso lo puedes hacer con timestamp. Sería la condición del switch.

Comment: ahora mismo es varchar, pero estoy intentando cambiarlo a date

Comment: es mejor para la integridad de la base de datos y para trabajar con los valores

Comment: Ya la tengo como date